# Can I start a .sh script that will start a program but also close it?

Tags: shell-script

So I’m not sure if this makes sense so I’ll try and elaborate.

I have this program (frontend) which can be started using ./frontend. The terminal stays on the program until you type in ! (Or ctrl C). What I want to do would be something like

```
./frontend.sh 
Wait 30
!
```

But it gets stuck on the program. I can also kill it using killall frontend in another terminal however this doesn’t help me do it in a script. Is there any way I can overcome this?

Comment: It depends how your program interacts with the terminal - if it reads standard input, you could try something like `printf '%s\n' 'Wait 30' '!' | ./frontend`

Comment: Can you use `timeout 30 ./frontend.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

The shell executes each command sequentially unless instructed otherwise. If your script calls `frontend.sh`, and  `frontend.sh` does not exit, then the shell will just be waiting for it to exit, and never execute the following commands.

One way to accomplish your goal is to start `frontend.sh` in the background with the `&` operator, and then kill it by passing its process ID -- available via the special parameter `$!` -- to the `kill` command.

```
#!/bin/sh

# start frontend.sh in the background
./frontend.sh &

sleep 30

# the special parameter $! holds the process ID of the last background process
if kill $!; then
    echo "frontend.sh was killed, do more work here"
else
    echo "failed to kill frontend.sh, handle the error here"
fi
```